# How to build a facebook web-crawler?

Tags: facebook, web-crawler

How can I construct a program that goes through all posts on a facebook page, and collects the names of all people who interact with the posts, through sharing, commenting, etc?

The main problem is that some pages contain thousands of posts, and unless there is a way to show one post at a time, it will require a lot of memory.

How can I achieve this as effectively as possible, without needing to download alot of images and other stuff that I don't need?

Comment: Yeah cause that doesn’t sound like an invasion or privacy. Why do you want to harvest peoples names? What’s your goal here? I’d be careful on what you plan t do with these names if you don’t have their permission to use their data.

Comment: You should read Facebook Platform Policy to make sure what you are doing is allowed.